# How can I jquery event bubbling handling correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm struggling with some jquery code that need to be event bubbling handling correctly. I'll show you some simplified code snip to exaplain, what I want to do.

HTML

```
<div class='warp'>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
  <select name="foo"  class='foo-selector'>
    <option value="foo1">foo1</option>
    <option value="foo2">foo2</option>
    <option value="foo3">foo3</option>
  </select>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
  <select name="bar" class='bar-selector'>
    <option value="bar1">bar1</option>
    <option value="bar2">bar2</option>
    <option value="bar3">bar3</option>
  </select>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
  <select name="baz" class='baz-selector'>
    <option value="baz1">baz1</option>
    <option value="baz2">baz2</option>
    <option value="baz3">baz3</option>
  </select>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

jquery script below

```
$(document).on('change', $('.foo-selector'), function(e){
  console.log('foo-changed');
 
});
$(document).on('change', $('.bar-selector'), function(){
  console.log('bar-changed');
});

$(document).on('change', $('.baz-selector'), function(){
  console.log('baz-changed');
});
```

When I changed bar selector's value and output is

```
"foo-changed"
"bar-changed"
"baz-changed"
```

In the some way, I changed baz selector and output is the same.

I have some knowledge about event capture and bubbling of jquery (actually, jquery doesn't have event capture phase though) to understand why output like above happend.

But, in this case, apparently foo and baz selectors was not changed thier value and I don't want execute event that not changed actually.

Is thare any way to avoid this gotcha?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `$('.foo-selector')` to `'.foo-selector'` and it works fine.

When you do it like below you don't need to wrap the selector in `$()`

```
$(document).on('change', '.foo-selector', function(e) {
  console.log('foo-changed');
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).on('change', '.foo-selector', function(e) {
  console.log('foo-changed');

});
$(document).on('change', '.bar-selector', function() {
  console.log('bar-changed');
});

$(document).on('change', '.baz-selector', function() {
  console.log('baz-changed');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='warp'>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select name="foo" class='foo-selector'>
          <option value="foo1">foo1</option>
          <option value="foo2">foo2</option>
          <option value="foo3">foo3</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select name="bar" class='bar-selector'>
          <option value="bar1">bar1</option>
          <option value="bar2">bar2</option>
          <option value="bar3">bar3</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select name="baz" class='baz-selector'>
          <option value="baz1">baz1</option>
          <option value="baz2">baz2</option>
          <option value="baz3">baz3</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```